# C++20 error: <function-style-cast> cannot convert initializer list to std::string

Tags: c++, string, c++20, initializer-list

I'm working with C++20 and trying to use an initializer list to initialize a std::string variable. However, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error C2440 "<function-style-cast>": "initializer list" cannot be converted to "std::string
```

and

```
Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" matches the argument list
```

Relevant code:

```
std::pair<int, std::vector<std::string>> split(const std::string& s, char delimiter) {
    using namespace std::ranges;

    std::vector<std::string> tokens;

    auto str_view = views::all(s);
    auto split_view = str_view | views::split(delimiter);

    for (auto&& rng : split_view) {
        tokens.push_back(std::string(rng.begin(), rng.end()));
    }

    return { tokens.empty() ? 0x1002 : 0x0000, std::move(tokens) };
```

This line returns me an error( in particular the string call ):

```
tokens.push_back(std::string(rng.begin(), rng.end()));
```

What am I doing wrong and should this not be possible?

I expected it to just return me my subtoken without error.
I mean I can just use a while loop with a string_view but I would like to know what I did wrong.

Comment: Is that the full and complete error output? Please include the full and complete *build* log when asking questions about build errors. And add comments in the shown code on the lines where you get the error.

Comment: compiles for me: https://godbolt.org/z/ePaoneGxv please show a [mre] and the full error message

Comment: You're not initializing any `std::string` variable, and there is no initialzer list in the line you indicate. Are you referring to some other code?

Comment: Btw.: `tokens.emplace_back(rng.begin(), rng.end());`

Comment: @AlanBirtles OP is not compiling with gcc but the microsoft compiler, which is notoriously broken and incomplete.

Comment: @bitmask True..

Comment: @bitmask actually MSVC has been faster to implement a lot of c++20 than others, this works there as well https://godbolt.org/z/7W3cjWPYM. MSVC was "broken and incomplete" a long time ago but is now a lot better and no worse than GCC (just in different ways)

Comment: @DoItWithFlow Can you create an example in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Kh1cbva1G) that reproduces the error using MSVC?

Comment: @DoItWithFlow Don't listen to bitmask, MSVC is just fine and superior on Windows computer

Comment: @TedLyngmo I just tried and it always compiles fine. Even when i combine it with my call and the relevant other code. Only Visual Studio seems unhappy about it. Im a little confused.

Comment: @DoItWithFlow I just copied my example program into VS2022 and it compiled clean.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work before 19.31: https://godbolt.org/z/MPef58Yns, note that  19.30 doesn't support ranges in `/std:c++20` mode and requires `/std:c++latest` instead due to the implementation not being complete

Comment: @DoItWithFlow What version of VS are you using? The latest is 17.6.0 Preview 2.0.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes. I was using 17.0. On the newest Snapshot it doesnt throw any errors. That was a dumb mistake.

Comment: @DoItWithFlow Easy mistake to make :-) Glad it worked out!

Comment: you probably shouldn't be using `/std:c++latest` unless you really have to, using a specific standard version will protect you from using experimental implementations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-170